# Last Page Blank in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with a group.My report has a blank page at the end of the report. My report is only Two page but it prints a blank one page at last.when i export to PDF,  i will get this blank page also. Both the Page Footer and Report Footer have a checkmark in the "Suppress(No-Drill-Down)" but it is greyed out.  I was going to add a formula in x-2 'pagenumber = TotalPageCount' but I can't get to it.  Is there anything else that I need to check that could be causing this?

Answer (score -1):

Try the fix detailed [here](https://kb.blackbaud.co.uk/articles/Article/62942)

You should try the instructions under

> If the "New Page After" checkbox is marked for Group Footer #1, conditionally suppress it for the last page.

On your group:
-Section Expert - New Page After (click X+2 button)
-Set this formula `Not(OnLastRecord)`

If it doesn't work, please post a screenshot of your layout if you can.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)